# Python XPath exclude item

Tags: python, xpath

I have XML. I need you to take all XML except for the first IMG tag

```
<img width=\"1200\" height=\"673\" src=\"https://clutchpoints.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/Gilbert-Arenas-Dominique-Wilkins-Steve-Kerr-Magic.jpg\" class=\"webfeedsFeaturedVisual wp-post-image\" alt=\"Gilbert Arenas Dominique Wilkins Steve Kerr Magic\" style=\"display: block; margin-bottom: 5px; clear:both;max-width: 100%;\" link_thumbnail=\"\" srcset=\"https://clutchpoints.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/Gilbert-Arenas-Dominique-Wilkins-Steve-Kerr-Magic.jpg 1200w, https://clutchpoints.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/Gilbert-Arenas-Dominique-Wilkins-Steve-Kerr-Magic-300x168.jpg 300w, https://clutchpoints.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/Gilbert-Arenas-Dominique-Wilkins-Steve-Kerr-Magic-1024x574.jpg 1024w, https://clutchpoints.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/Gilbert-Arenas-Dominique-Wilkins-Steve-Kerr-Magic-768x431.jpg 768w\" sizes=\"(max-width: 1200px) 100vw, 1200px\" /><p>Even the most avid of NBA fans are unable to keep a mental record of every team all the greats have ever played in. That&#8217;s just impossible. This is especially the case when these stints are rather forgettable or possibly short-lived. Aside from Shaquille O&#8217;Neal, Dwight Howard, and Penny Hardaway, a few more stars played [&#8230;]</p>\n<p>The post <a rel=\"nofollow\" href=\"https://clutchpoints.com/5-best-players-who-played-for-the-magic-that-you-forgot-about/\">5 best players who played for the Magic that you forgot about</a> appeared first on <a rel=\"nofollow\" href=\"https://clutchpoints.com\">ClutchPoints</a>.</p>\n
```

this does not work

`//div/*[not(img)]`

Comment: Please edit your post to show the actual code that is not working.  also,  you might want to format the xml so that its not on a single line.

Comment: Also the string you have posted does not appear to be valid xml but rather an attempt to encode an xml into a python string?

Comment: Maybe try something like `//div/img[position() > 1]`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is your HTML data :

```
<div>
<img width="1200" height="673" src="https://clutchpoints.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/Gilbert-Arenas-Dominique-Wilkins-Steve-Kerr-Magic.jpg" class="webfeedsFeaturedVisual wp-post-image" alt="Gilbert Arenas Dominique Wilkins Steve Kerr Magic" style="display: block; margin-bottom: 5px; clear:both;max-width: 100%;" link_thumbnail="" srcset="https://clutchpoints.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/Gilbert-Arenas-Dominique-Wilkins-Steve-Kerr-Magic.jpg 1200w, https://clutchpoints.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/Gilbert-Arenas-Dominique-Wilkins-Steve-Kerr-Magic-300x168.jpg 300w, https://clutchpoints.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/Gilbert-Arenas-Dominique-Wilkins-Steve-Kerr-Magic-1024x574.jpg 1024w, https://clutchpoints.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/Gilbert-Arenas-Dominique-Wilkins-Steve-Kerr-Magic-768x431.jpg 768w" sizes="(max-width: 1200px) 100vw, 1200px"/>
<p>Even the most avid of NBA fans are unable to keep a mental record of every team all the greats have ever played in. That&#8217;s just impossible. This is especially the case when these stints are rather forgettable or possibly short-lived. Aside from Shaquille O&#8217;Neal, Dwight Howard, and Penny Hardaway, a few more stars played [&#8230;]</p>
<p>The post <a rel="nofollow" href="https://clutchpoints.com/5-best-players-who-played-for-the-magic-that-you-forgot-about/">5 best players who played for the Magic that you forgot about</a> appeared first on <a rel="nofollow" href="https://clutchpoints.com">ClutchPoints</a>.</p>
</div>
```

You can use the following XPath expression to get all elements except the img, use `self` axis in combination with `not` :

```
//div/*[not(self::img)]
```

Output : 4 nodes (2 `p`, 2 `a`)